# Why does the water becomes gray when I move the viewport?

Tags: 3d-view

From above works properly
[image]

When I move the visual down, it appears gray even in the render
[image]

Until it appears all grey
[image]

The plane fills the pool entirely, maybe there's some problem with FOV or something like?

Comment: can you provide your blend- file?

Comment: Ye sure, we transfer link : https://we.tl/t-x3PuQ2Yx9m

Comment: Most likely is an issue related to the fresnel or IOR settings for the material (which we now nothing about) and how the background is being reflected on the surface. That gray are is the environment.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by using Shadow Ray in the light path as fac on the mix shader?

Comment: Susu shadow ray is needed for depth of the water, otherwise it seems flat. But seems that without it the problem doesn't occur, but i rly need it. Is there a way to replace it with something else similar?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have your Normals pointing in the wrong direction. Check your normals and ensure they are pointing ‘out’ of the water.

With the normals pointing into the body of water it will be rendering as if the fluid is outside a cavity of air. What you’re seeing is Total Internal Reflection as the light is refracted at the surface - the wrong way to what you’re expecting.